# How to use the state of one observable to skip values of another observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

This is best explained with a short example.
let's say this is my source observable that I want to filter

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

I use a checkbox to handle the filter state. When the box is not checked, I want to skip all values.
I use RxAndroid to get an observable for the checkbox like this:

```
RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(checkBox)
```

here is my code:

```
    Observable.combineLatest(
            RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(checkBox)
            , Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            , (isChecked, intervalCounter) -> {
                if (!isChecked) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return intervalCounter;
                }
            }
    ).filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

and I get the desired output

```
interval       1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9  
checkbox       0-----1--------0-----1---
combineLatest
result         ------3--4--5--------8--9
```

I am just getting started with RxJava and my "solution" does not feel right, because:
You can see that the combine function returns a magic value `null` and then the filter will skip these `nulls`.
That means that the filter function is called even though I already know, that I want to skip this data.

- maybe I should use another operator
- is there a way to use the checkbox-observable in a filter function
- maybe there is some way in the combine function to signal that I want to skip this data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pictures of the desired output is not correct. In your implementation `combineLatest` is combining a `null` into the stream :

```
interval       1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9  
checkbox       0-----1--------0-----1---
combineLatest  N--N--3--4--5--N--N--8--9
filter(NonNull)------3--4--5--------8--9
```

IMHO, using `null` as a signal is not good in Rx Stream, developers can easily fall into `NullPointerException`.

To avoid the use of `null`, there are two measures. The first one is to transform the result to a Pair, and apply filter & map later.

A very simple `Pair` Class:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    T first;
    U second;

    public Pair(T first, U second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Then the whole implementation would like this:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
        RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(checkBox)
        , Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        , (isChecked, intervalCounter) -> new Pair<>(isChecked,intervalCounter)
).filter(pair -> pair.first)
 .map(pair -> pair.second)  // optional, do this if you only need the second part
```

The data flow:

```
interval          1      2      3      4
                  |      |      |      |
checkbox        F |  T   |   F  |  T   F
                  |  |   |   |  |  |   |
combineLatest    F1  T1  T2  F2 F3 T3  F4
                     |   |         |
filter(first=T)      T1  T2        T3
                     |   |         | 
map(second)          1   2         3
```

Or if you can Java 8 in your project, use `Optional` to avoid `null`, which is very similar to your solution but it gives the awareness for others developers that the Stream signal is `Optional`.

```
Observable<Optional<Integer>> o1 = Observable.combineLatest(
        RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(checkBox)
        , Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        , (isChecked, intervalCounter) -> {
            if (!isChecked) {
                return Optional.empty();
            } else {
                return Optional.of(intervalCounter);
            }
        }
)

Observable<Integer> o2 = o1.filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
```

Some easier approach which is not same with `combineLatest` but identical to your desired result pictures.

```
// Approach 1
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).filter( i -> checkBox.isEnabled())

// Approach 2
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .withLatestFrom(
    RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(checkBox),
    (isChecked, intervalCounter) -> {
            if (!isChecked) {
                return Optional.empty();
            } else {
                return Optional.of(intervalCounter);
            }
     }).filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)
```