# Change button state base on selection with RxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new with RxJava2 and I try to achieve this but I don't know how to:
I have 3 checkbox and a button. I want the button to be enable only when all the checkbox are checked. Then if the button is enable and the user unchecks a box the button should be disabled again.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding
And read this: 1) https://www.ykode.com/2015/02/20/android-frp-rxjava-retrolambda.html 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058777/how-to-use-the-state-of-one-observable-to-skip-values-of-another-observable

Comment: Thx! I was helpful

Comment: You welcome...